# How to close bootstrap datetimepicker when date is selected

Tags: asp.net, hide, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/).

When I select the date the picker does not hides and I have to click outside to close it.
How to close datetimepicker when date is selected/clicked?

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <asp:TextBox ID="date2" class="form-control" runat="server"
    onfocus="this.style.backgroundColor='yellow'"
    onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='cyan'"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('#date2').datetimepicker();
    });
  </script> 
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="col-sm-3">
     <asp:TextBox ID="date2" class="form-control" runat="server"    onfocus="this.style.backgroundColor='yellow'"  onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='cyan'"/> 
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
     $('#date2').datetimepicker();
     });              
     </script> 
     </div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force the datetimepicker to hide itself with the following piece of code.

```
$('#date2').data("DateTimePicker").hide();
```

For other functions like `hide` please consider checking out the [documentation](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/).

Comment: Thanks Izzet! i think i am doing something wrong... <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#date2').datetimepicker();
                $('#date2').data("DateTimePicker").hide();
            });            
       
             </script>

Comment: Then try this: `$("#date").on("dp.change", function() { $("#date2").data("DateTimePicker").hide(); });` Also, there is an option called `keepOpen` that you could pass as **false** in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot Izzet. It is working fine. Can we hide time part from the date.

Comment: To hide the time part, pass format option in the initialization method as MM/dd/YYYY. Please check out the documentation in this regard: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format